# How to implement backpropagation for a deep convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I've recently started reading Andrew W. Trask's Grokking Deep Learning book and implemented the CNN, it works great but then I tried to add more hidden CNN layers and failed, I just couldn't get the dimensions fit for the CNN backpropagation.

My code is the following:

```
for iteration in range(iterations):
  '''
  images: (1000, 3, 32, 32)
  kernel_rows, kernel_cols, num_colors = 4,4,3
  num_kernels_1, num_kernels_2 = 15, 30

  hidden_size = ((input_rows - 2*kernel_rows) * (input_cols - 2*kernel_cols)) * num_kernels_2
  The size the matrix has that is the output after doing 2 convolutions 
  (thats why its 2*kernel_rows and 2*kernel_cols)

  kernels_1 = (kernel_rows*kernel_cols * num_colors, num_kernels_1)
  kernels_2 = (kernel_rows*kernel_cols * num_kernels_1, num_kernels_2)
  weights_1 = (hidden_size,100)
  weights_2 = (100,30)
  weights_3 = (30,10)
  '''
  sample_size = len(images)

  C_0 = convolution(images, input_rows, input_cols, kernel_rows, kernel_cols)

  C_1 = tanh(C_0 @ kernels_1)
  C_1_flattened = C_1.reshape(sample_size, -1)
  C_1 = C_1.reshape(sample_size, -1, (input_rows - kernel_rows), (input_cols - kernel_cols))
  C_1 = convolution(C_1, C_1.shape[2], C_1.shape[3], kernel_rows, kernel_cols)

  C_2 = tanh(C_1 @ kernels_2)
  C_2 = C_2.reshape(sample_size, -1)

  Z_1 = C_2 @ weights_1
  A_1 = tanh(Z_1)

  Z_2 = A_1 @ weights_2
  A_2 = tanh(Z_2)

  Z_3 = A_2 @ weights_3
  A_3 = softmax(Z_3)

  delta_A_3 = (labels - A_3) / len(images)
  delta_A_2 = (delta_A_3 @ weights_3.T) * tanh2deriv(A_2)
  delta_A_1 = (delta_A_2 @ weights_2.T) * tanh2deriv(A_1)

  delta_C_2 = (delta_A_1 @ weights_1.T) * tanh2deriv(C_2)
  k_update_2 = C_1.reshape(kernel_rows*kernel_cols*num_kernels_1,-1) @ delta_C_2.reshape(-1, num_kernels_2)
  
  delta_C_1 = (delta_C_2.reshape(sample_size, -1, num_kernels_2) @ kernels_2.T) * tanh2deriv(C_1)
  k_update_1 = C_0.reshape(kernel_rows*kernel_cols*num_colors, -1) @ delta_C_1.reshape(-1, num_kernels_1)

  cost = np.sum((labels - A_3)**2) / len(images)
  
  weights_3 += alpha * (A_3.T @ delta_A_3)
  weights_2 += alpha * (A_2.T @ delta_A_2)
  weights_1 += alpha * (A_1.T @ delta_A_1)
  kernels_2 -= alpha * k_update_2
  kernels_1 -= alpha * k_update_1
  
  print(str(cost)[:8])
```

The problematic line is the one where i calculate `k_update_1` where `C_0.reshape(kernel_rows*kernel_cols*num_colors, -1)` has the shape (48, 784000) and `delta_C_1.reshape(-1, num_kernels_1)` the shape (9216000, 15), I'm trying to update my kernels_1 matrix with the shape (48,15) which obviously doesn't add up.

The helper functions are:

```
def convolution(data, input_rows, input_cols, kernel_rows, kernel_cols):
  sects = []
  for row_start in range(input_rows - kernel_rows):
    for col_start in range(input_cols - kernel_cols):
      section = get_image_section(data,
                                  row_start,
                                  row_start + kernel_rows,
                                  col_start,
                                  col_start + kernel_cols)
      sects.append(section)
  
  expanded_input = np.concatenate(sects, axis = 1)
  es = expanded_input.shape
  return expanded_input.reshape(es[0], es[1], -1)
```

and:

```
def get_image_section(layer, row_from, row_to, col_from, col_to):
  section = layer[:,:, row_from:row_to, col_from:col_to]
  return np.expand_dims(section, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found  a solution for my problem, I had to undo the convolution before i could multiply the 2 matrices, i did this with the following function:

```
def reverse_convolution(data, sample_size, num_kernels, kernel_rows, kernel_cols, output_shape, stride):
  data_expanded_dims = data.reshape(sample_size, -1, num_kernels, kernel_rows, kernel_cols)
  output = np.zeros(output_shape)
  data_row = 0
  for row_start in range(0, output_shape[2] - kernel_rows, stride):
    for col_start in range(0, output_shape[3] - kernel_rows, stride):
      output[:,:,row_start:row_start+kernel_rows,col_start:col_start+kernel_cols] = data_expanded_dims[:, data_row, :]
      data_row += 1
  return output.reshape(sample_size, -1)
```

I use the function after declaring delta_C_1 like this:

```
  delta_C_1_reverse_conv = reverse_convolution(delta_C_1, sample_size, num_kernels_1, kernel_rows, kernel_cols,
                                               output_shape = C_1_shape, stride = stride)
```

with C_1_shape being the shape of C_1 before the convolution